# Jomsocial connect

Tags: joomla-extensions

what are the popular connects available for jomsocial ie to connect it to facebook, gmail, yahoo etc... and to import friends from the same

Answer (score 0):

you can try mod_hellome or mod_jomsocialconnect. Read about these on Jomsocial site. There is lot of documentation. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

JFBC (Jomsocial Facebook Connect) is the most feature full and advanced. Good support too. I looked into it quite carefully. Jomsocial is also building integration for JFBC natively into Jomsocial 3 as a alternative option to their own:

http://www.sourcecoast.com/forums/jfbconnect/jfbconnect-joomla-3x-support/6462-jomsocial-3-integration